# Custom annotation image rotates only at the beginning of the Program (Swift- iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, annotations, uiviewanimation

Please help out a beginner iOS developer here! :) So, I have a timer which gets the latitude and longitude of a bus periodically from a xml sheet which provides real-time locations of the bus. I was able to setup the parser, animate the bus movement and setup a custom (arrow) image for the bus.

However, the problem is, I'm not able to able to rotate the bus-annotation everytime I get new values for the latitude and longitude. The `busAnnotation` rotates only when the program starts, but not everytime the direction of the bus is updated.

Below is my xml `parser` function, which calculates the `busDirection` everytime the location changes. The value of `busDirection` changes correctly with location changes, but it doesn't apply to the rotation for some reason as the timer goes on. The movement of the annotation is also well-animated, it just doesn't rotate other than when the program is started.

```
// Some constants
var oldLatitude: Double? = 44.97234
var oldLongitude: Double? = -93.2446329
var busDirection: CLLocationDirection()

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didStartElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!, attributes attributeDict: NSDictionary!) {
    if (elementName == "vehicle") {
        var latitude = attributeDict["lat"]?.doubleValue            // Get latitude of bus from xml
        var longitude = attributeDict["lon"]?.doubleValue           // Get longitude of bus from xml

        if (oldLatitude == latitude && oldLongitude == longitude) {
            return
        }
        else {  // Update bus location         
            busDirection = directionBetweenPoints(MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(oldLatitude!, oldLongitude!)), destinationPoint: MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude!, longitude!)))       // Get direction of bus:

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {
                self.busAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude!, longitude!)                  
                self.mapView(self.map, viewForAnnotation: self.busAnnotation).annotation = self.busAnnotation
                self.map.addAnnotation(self.busAnnotation)                 
            }

            oldLatitude = latitude
            oldLongitude = longitude
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the 'viewForAnnotation' that I implemented in order to change the image of the annotation and supposedly rotate it

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
    let reuseId = "pin" 
    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView  

    if pinView == nil {
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        pinView!.image = imageWithImage(UIImage(named:"arrow.png")!, scaledToSize: CGSize(width: 25.0, height: 25.0))       // Set custom image for annotation and resize it         
    }
    else {
        pinView!.annotation = annotation
    }   

    // Rotate the annotation.
    pinView?.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.map.transform, CGFloat(degreesToRadians(self.busDirection)))
    return pinView
}
```

These are some of the helper functions that I used in the above methods:

```
// For rotating bus annotations:
func degreesToRadians(degrees: Double) -> Double { return degrees * M_PI / 180.0 }
func radiansToDegrees(radians: Double) -> Double { return radians * 180.0 / M_PI }

func directionBetweenPoints(sourcePoint: MKMapPoint, destinationPoint : MKMapPoint) -> CLLocationDirection {
    let x : Double = destinationPoint.x - sourcePoint.x;
    let y : Double = destinationPoint.y - sourcePoint.y;

    return fmod(radiansToDegrees(atan2(y, x)), 360.0) + 90.0;
}
```

Do you guys think I'm missing something here? How would I rotate the bus-annotation everytime the locations are updated? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks a lot man the snippet really helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rotation only occurs the first time the map view creates the view for the annotation. Rather than create a new view every time an annotation updates, it simply moves the view. That's much more efficient for the map view to do.
So, what you should do is make the `pinView` a property, instantiate it in your init method, return that in `mapView(, viewForAnnotation:)` and apply the rotation directly to that `pinView` in your animation block.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {
    self.busAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude!, longitude!)                  
    self.map.addAnnotation(self.busAnnotation)
    if let pv = self.pinView {
        pv.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.map.transform, CGFloat(degreesToRadians(self.busDirection)))
    }              
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! You saved my life! Thanks a lot! :D